# Calculate Percentage from Two Columns and Add Value to New Data Frame

Tags: r

I want to calculate the percentage of observations that match a certain criteria and then add that value to a new data frame in a cell that has the same criteria as the column and row names. I then want to create a separate data frame for each month represented in the data. The data I'm pulling from looks like this:

```
Occurrence    Total    Criteria1    Criteria2    Month
1             20       A            2016         Jan
5             50       B            2016         Feb
0             10       C            2016         Mar
1             50       A            2017         Jan
5             10       B            2017         Feb
0             20       C            2017         Mar
```

The new data frames would look like this:

```
(Jan)     2016    2017
A         0.05    0.02

(Feb)
B         0.1     0.5

(Mar)
C         0       0
```

So I'm trying to write a for loop or something comparable that calculates the percentage of occurrences and then add them to a new, empty data frame based on the criteria on which they were grouped in the first place. So far my code looks like this:

```
for(i in unique(data$month)){
df %>%
group_by(Criteria1, Criteria2) %>%
summarise(Perc = Occurrence / Total) %>%
spread(Criteria2, Perc)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `xtabs`

```
xtabs(Perc ~ Criteria1 + Criteria2, transform(df, Perc = Occurrence / Total))
#    Criteria2
#Criteria1 2016 2017
#        A 0.05 0.02
#        B 0.10 0.50
#        C 0.00 0.00
```

Or a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(Criteria1, Criteria2) %>%
    summarise(Perc = Occurrence / Total) %>%
    spread(Criteria2, Perc)
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   Criteria1 [3]
#  Criteria1 `2016` `2017`
#  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A           0.05   0.02
#2 B           0.1    0.5
#3 C           0      0
```

---

### Update

For your updated data

```
df %>%
    group_by(Criteria1, Criteria2, Month) %>%
    summarise(Perc = Occurrence / Total) %>%
    spread(Criteria2, Perc)
## A tibble: 3 x 4
## Groups:   Criteria1 [3]
#  Criteria1 Month `2016` `2017`
#  <fct>     <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         Jan     0.05   0.02
#2 B         Feb     0.1    0.5
#3 C         Mar     0      0
```

Or something like this in base R

```
xtabs(
    Perc ~ Criteria1 + Criteria2, 
    transform(df, Perc = Occurrence / Total, Criteria1 = paste(Criteria1, Month, sep = "_")))
#    Criteria2
#Criteria1 2016 2017
#A_Jan 0.05 0.02
#B_Feb 0.10 0.50
#C_Mar 0.00 0.00
```

Comment: Say there was a third column that gave time of year like an additional column showing the month of each row. Can I write a for loop to run the above tidy code for every unique month that appears and then creates a whole data frame devoted to just that one month?

Comment: @Kardinol That would certainly be possible without a `for` loop. Can you edit your post to include representative sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, to make it more clear I want to generate a new data frame for each month, not group them by month in the same data frame. The output should show 3 data frames with 1 row each.

Comment: @Kardinol You *could* append the `dplyr` chain with `... %>% split(., .$Month)` to split the `data.frame` into a `list` of `data.frame`s for every `Month`. *However*, I would advise against such a structure. There is really no point in splitting the data in such a way, as entries are uniquely identifiable through the `Month`, `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` values. Can you elaborate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually I see your point. Everything is in one data frame which makes it easier than referring to multiple. Thanks for your help!